# Connect to another host from inside mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, mariadb, connectivity

I have two virtual servers on one physical machine.

There are MySQL users and passwords the same for both of them.

I want to write something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM [host_name].[db_name].[table_name]
```

Federated / FederatedX is not a solution for me. At least I want to avoid using it if it is possible.

If what I want is not possible I need some solution to do the following:

I have two MySQL servers: server1 and server2.

I want to set a trigger on a few tables in server1 so i.e. when new row appears there a part of that row should go to server2.

I don't want an entire row to be replicated. There might be some values on which I will want to remove some rows form server2 and e.t.c.

I was thinking I should call some procedure on the trigger if it is possible.

Comment: And why isn't  federation  a solution for you?

Comment: I just wanted a better solution, though there would be [host_name].[db_name].[table_name] solution but I couldn't find one. I'm gonna go with federated for now unless anyone gives me some better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  One connection can talk to only one MySQL server.
Any Stored Routine lives in a single MySQL server, so another connection is not allowed for.

Comment: Any update on the solution? Is it still not possible to connect different host? I did try to search but didn't find anything.

Comment: Well, MariaDB has ENGINE=FEDERATEDX

Comment: Thank you, I will check.